# WAF (Web Application Firewall) の Siteguard で "監視" が検出された場合、問題はありませんか？

Tags: security, waf

WAFで検知されるものには以下のように「拒否・監視・安全」がありますが、検知種別が「監視（monitor）」の場合は、特に大きな問題はないと判断してもいいものなのでしょうか？

なにかアドバイスいただけますと幸いです。

- 拒否
  ("block", "BLOCK"):
  リクエストを拒否し、検出メッセージをクライアントに応答します。
- 監視
  ("monitor", "MONITOR"):
  記録(ログ出力、メール通知)のみ行います。リクエストは拒否されずに通過します。
- 安全
  ("WHITE"):
  該当リクエストを安全なアクセスとみなします。
  カスタム・シグネチャの各条件で設定可能です。

Answer (score 1):

WAFといっても様々な製品やサービスがあり、同じ製品やサービスによっても、カスタマイズ可能な多くの設定があります。同じ通信の内容であっても、拒否するのか、記録だけするのか、安全とみなすのかは、製品・サービスによっても異なりますし、設定内容によっても異なります。

どのような通信を記録だけの「監視」とするのかは、そのWAFを構築・設定する時の方針によって変わります。「監視」とされた通信の危険性の度合いや検出時にどのような対処をすべきかは、どのようなものを「監視」としたのかという方針次第と言うことです。つまり、「一般的にどうすべきか」と言う答えはありません。その方針を決めたであろう人(WAFを構築・設定した人)に聞くしかありません。細かい設定をせずに、デフォルトの設定のままであるというのであれば、WAFの製品・サービスのマニュアルを見るか、サポートに問い合わせてください。

Comment: raccyさん、迅速なご回答いただきありがとうございました！
ご返信がおそくなり恐れ入りますが、ご回答いただいた内容を踏まえ、改めてマニュアルを読み込んでみようと思いました。最終手段として、サポートに問い合わせてみます